# React not responding to key down event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement some very basic key press detection and I can't get it to work at all. I have a bare component that should be picking up on the `onKeyDown` event but nothing gets logged out in the console:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleKeyDown(event) {
    console.log('handling a key press');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ChildComponent onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} />
    );
  }
}

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `ChildComponent` is not a component but a component factory. It will be replaced with the result of rendering the element created with that factory.

Insert the `ChildComponent` in a div and attach any event listener to the div, not `ChildComponent`. Replace `<div>` with `<span>` if you need inline display.

```
let {Component} = React;

class ChildComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( <child-component>press down a key</child-component> );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  handleKeyDown(event) {
    console.log('handling a key press');
  }

  render() {
    return ( <div onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}><ChildComponent  /></div> );
  }
}

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

See it in action on [codepen](http://codepen.io/widged/pen/epNPjv)

Comment: I've noticed this trying to apply styles, too. Rather than applying to the top-level DOM element inside the component, the styles are just dropped on the floor.

Comment: Your answer is misleading. onClick and onKeyDown are different events.

Comment: @bhagyash-ingale Edited with onKeyDown. Sorry for any confusion, I had not perceived the type of event as relevant to the OP issue.

Answer (score 35):

You'll need to assign a `tabIndex`-attribute for your element (the wrapping element for example) for it to receive keypresses. Then pass the keyDown handler to it with the props:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div tabIndex="0" onKeyDown={this.props.handleKeyDown}>Fooo</div> 
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleKeyDown(event) {
    console.log('handling a key press');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ChildComponent handleKeyDown={() => this.handleKeyDown()} />
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Any reason why it needs a tab index ?

Comment: @user1095118 it's the only way elements beside links and form elements can receive keyboard focus and thus key presses. It's set to zero so that it doesn't override the native tab order. See http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex for more information.

Answer (score 14):

The DOM wants the element to be focused in order to receive the keyboard event. If you don't want to hack the element with `tabIndex` or `contentEditable` to get it to focus, you could use native DOM event listeners on `window`, and define a different handler in each component that handles keyboard events.

Just be sure to remove the event listener when that component unmounts so all components aren't handling all the time:

```
  componentWillMount: function() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
  },
```

Also, there appears to be an npm that provides similar functionality if that's easier: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-keydown

Comment: Remember to bind your event handler in the constructor if you want `this` to be the component:  

`this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)`

Comment: This is the real solution to the question. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

In an app my team is working on, we're using [react-hotkey](https://github.com/glenjamin/react-hotkey). Unfortunately, React doesn't seem to support mixins with ES6 syntax, but if you're cool with some babel, you could give it a try.

```
let App = React.createClass({
  mixins: [hotkey.Mixin('handleKeyDown')],

  componentDidMount() {
    hotkey.activate();
  },

  componentWillUnmount() {
    hotkey.disable();
  },

  handleKeyDown(event) {
    console.log('handling a key press');
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <ChildComponent />
    );
  }
});

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```