# App Component onKeyDown not firing in App component

Tags: reactjs

I am getting no response from the keydown function here, tried calling it on the div container aswell but still isn't firing.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default function App() {

  const keydown = () => {
    console.log('pressed');
  }

  return (
    <div id="container">
        <button onKeyDown={keydown}>
          test
        </button>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Add `tabIndex="0"` to the `<button>`

Comment: you either move the eventHandler to the document or focus the button.

Answer (score 1):

Although it may differ for other libs components, for `<button />` in React you can:

- use **onClick** for mouse click event
- use **onKeyPress** for keyboard event

---

Refer:

- React document: [keyboard-events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events)
- Assign an index: [React not responding to key down event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32445016/11872246)

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const keydown = () => {
    console.log("pressed");
  };
  const click = () => {
    console.log("clicked");
  };

  return (
    <div id="container">
      <button onKeyPress={keydown}>Press</button>
      <button onClick={click}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

[image]

Try it online:

[image: Edit tender-zhukovsky-jmy3h]

Comment: @riazosama Try it after you give the focus. It's not a form-submit

Comment: can you update your answer so that it works? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Extending from the @keikai answer, the convenient approach would be to focus the Button when the component loads. This can be done easily using a combination of `useRef` and `useEffect` hooks.

```
import React from "react";
const {useRef, useEffect } = React;


export default function App() {
  const keydown = () => {
    console.log("pressed");
  };

  const inputRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.focus()
  }, [])



  return (
    <div id="container">
      <button ref={inputRef} onKeyDown={keydown}>Press</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, what if I reuse the component though? so that there are multiple buttons all displayed at once?